# can't connect to internet with ubuntu 17.10

Tags: networking, internet, gksudo

I have a fresh install of ubuntu 17.10 .. After installation, I was able to browse the internet, but 1 day later, and even though wi-fi appears listed as working, it is not.

I've searched around for some solution to this and have seen that I should run

```
gksudo gedit /etc/NetWorkManager/NetworkManger.conf
```

and make changes there.. however, `gksudo` is not something which comes with 17.10, I think, and I can't install it as no internet..

**Is there a work around for this problem?**

And since this is apparently a bug from 17.04 (?) is it not fixed in 17.10?

Comment: `gksudo` is for x/x11 environments, and won't work in wayland (wayland is default for 17.10 if you're hardware can handle it though error is "can't open display").   you're just using an editor (gedit) and raising privileges (gksudo) so i'd use `sudo vi ..` from a terminal instead (you can replace vi with nano or whatever editor you prefer).   If i was chasing a networking issue I'd be using `ping` etc & have a clear view on issue before I'd change the config.  NetworkManager can also be changed using network icon top right

Comment: You might want to make use of this [Ubuntu networking resource](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-troubleshooting.html), as there are quite a few things you can do to help narrow the Wi-Fi issues that you're experiencing, and in so doing, help us troubleshoot with you.

Comment: thanks for feedback.. i know very little about linux.. i am not sure why this worked, but i issued: sudo service network-manager restart           and since then everything is working fine,.

Answer (score 0):

first of all try

```
ping 192.168.1.1
```

or if you use a public wi-fi replace the 192.168.1.1 with your modem address

then if the packets lost your modem has problem

but if your modem is right try

```
ping 8.8.8.8
```

if packets back correctly open your terminal (with ctrl+alt+t or typing terminal in your dash) and write `sudo vim /etc/resolve.conf` (i use vim you can use your editor but it is better that your editor hasn't gui like gedit)
and then type your password and replace the ip address next of the nameserver with 8.8.8.8 and then type

you can test this with 4.2.2.4 or other dns address

and then ask your isp maybe they have a problem

by the way if you install tor purge it by `sudo apt purge tor` and then type `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service` maybe you can't install tor correctly

Comment: thanks amir.. sudo service network-manager restart fixed my problem..